# How to write a function that accepts a file name and returns the descriptive type for the file?

Tags: powershell

How can I write a function that accepts a file name and returns the descriptive type for the file in Powershell?

Basically, I want to create a new function called `Get-FileType`    where a file name is accepted `Get-FileType MyFile` and returns the file type such as `.txt`  So far, I must type `MyFile.txt` in order for extension to be returned.

If the registry doesn't contain the information, then I want it to return a string containing `"<type> File"`.  I would like the format to output "textfile" if file accepted is "myfile.txt"

So far I have this:
    `function Get-FileType ([string]$fileName = " ")
{ 
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filename)

```
$item = Get-Item HKLM:\Software\Classes\$extension


if ($filename -eq " ")
{
    write-host "no extension provided"
}
else {
    write-host $extension
    write-host $type
}
```

}`

I'm still stuck....

Comment: Based on your description of what you want, Input: A file name (e.g. "myfile.txt"), Output: the extension (e.g. ".txt"), what you want to do is just use the `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The call `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension("myfile.txt")` will return ".txt".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood exactly what you're asking for, but I have a few tips anyway :

1. to Get the extension of a precise file, you need to use the following command : `$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filename)`
2. I don't know what you mean by "descriptive type". In my registry, when I look at the key `HKLM:\Software\Classes\$extension` , the two values that are mostly available are "Content Type", and "Perceived Type"

if you want to get one of these values, e.g. "Content Type", then you could do something like :

```
function Get-FileType ([string]$fileName = " "){ 
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filename) 
    $item = Get-Item HKLM:\Software\Classes\$extension
    $item.GetValue("Content Type")
}
```

Then you need to add some controls to check if the file has no extension, or if the registry key does exist, or else you might get some errors...

Comment: Thanks gruntzy.  Does this mean that if were to perform `Get-FileType myfile.txt`, it will return `txt`?

I'm trying to create the function to get the extension of a file that is entered by the user.

Comment: Get-FileType myfile.txt will actually return something like _"text/plain"_. If you just want to get the file extension, then `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filename)` is enough